# Operations on JSON-structured data

Tags: json, visual-studio, f#

I would like to parse JSON-structured data contained in a `.txt` file. I correctly installed the `FSharp.Data` library, and set up the paths (I am still learning relative paths). Even so it throws an error that I cannot interpret.

```
#r "C:/Users/mauri/OneDrive/Programmazione1/Sharpstone/dataAccessManipulation/
packages/FSharp.Data.2.3.2/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll";;
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions
let value =  JsonValue.Load("C:/Users/mauri/OneDrive/Programmazione1/Sharpstone/SharpStone/Deck1")
```

Think of a simple operation as printing all the contents of the tag `collection`

```
for col in value?collectible do
  printfn "%s" (col.AsString())

 System.Exception: Not an object
```

This operation works on smaller pieces of data such the ones from the [tutorial](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html). Unfortunately, I still cannot make it work on a larger database (since it is quite heavy to the sight, please find it on my [GitHub account](https://github.com/Maurizio-Mario/Sharpstone/blob/master/SharpStone/deck1.txt) ). What is the reason of such an error, and what does "not an object" mean?

Comment: May I have a feedback about the downvote, in order to avoid it in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message "Not an object" means that you are trying to access a property of a JSON node that is not an object (with fields) but something else - such as collection.

Using the sample deck from GitHub, I suppose that `value` represents a collection and so writing `value?collectible` will give you this error - because you are trying to access a property `collectible` of something that is a collection.

The following (printing all artist names) should work:

```
let value =  JsonValue.Load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Maurizio-Mario/Sharpstone/master/SharpStone/deck1.txt")

for col in value.AsArray() do
  if col?collectible.AsBoolean() then
    printfn "%s" (col?artist.AsString())
```

That said, it is much easier to use the JSON type provider, which infers the type of the JSON document from a sample and then exposes all the properties in a type safe way:

```
 type Deck = JsonProvider<"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Maurizio-Mario/Sharpstone/master/SharpStone/deck1.txt">
let value = Deck.GetSamples()

for col in value do
  if col.Collectible then
    printfn "%s" col.Artist
```

Comment: I did not even think about arrays, they are still a new data structure to me, thanks!